# How to prevent duplicate request in soap object?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I have faced a very weird problem by using Soap object in android. I am running a background thread which will take care of sending data to server periodically. Here i am using Soap web service for sending data. While sending a data to server,Sometime duplicate request(double time sending same data) occurs in server.
How to overcome this issue? Please help me...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if there's any loop/condition which is causing the error.

Secondly always within a thread whenever HTTP requests are involved make them synchronized and set a boolean whenever request is fired. Reset the boolean ones the response is received successfully and then fire the next request.

These requests for synchronization can be queued in a list and ones a successful response is received remove the request from list else pop the request out and place according to your need (logically back at the end - so that other requests also get a chance if one is failing repetedly).

Comment: Actually i stored a bunch of data in sqlite. And then using do-while loop i extracted a each row and posting those data to the server. In the same loop i get the response and also verify the response. If its positive, I deleted the row in DB. Thats all i have done. is there any wrong in it.

Comment: The process seems to be pretty ok to me. However just try using while instead of a do while. Since Do while will run atleast ones. Do let me know if it works.